# I want to call/redirect to a Portal page from Struts2Portlet Action Class?

Tags: struts2, websphere-6.1

Hi We are developing a **Struts2Portlet** Application in WebSpherePortal6.0.1. In my application I want to redirect to another portlet page after fullfilling the validations in my **struts action** class.How to achieve it. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a jsp page contained within the same portlet you are working on a completely separate page in the portal system? Does it require cross portlet communication if a separate portlet?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done some R&D to fix this issue,finally i found a solution.We cant call/redirect the portal page from struts2Portlet Action class.We can have to give a result type in strut action class,then we have to configure the action in the result.

<action name="view" class="com.ibm.rock.ViewAction" method="prepareview">
<result name="view">*/view/viewportalpage.action*</result>
</action>

<action name="viewportalpage" class="com.ibm.rock.ViewAction" method="prepareview">
<result name="preview">/_Rock/jsp/html/Preview.jsp</result>
</action>
Synatax:
<result name="success">*/Namespace/view.action*</result>
<action name="view" class="com.ibm.rock.ViewAction" method="prepareview">
<result name="preview">/_Rock/jsp/html/Preview.jsp</result>
</action>
```